# How to debug websockets with wireshark

Tags: websocket, wireshark

I have hosted my websocket server using **python tornado server** on localhost **ws://localhost:8001** and client is on another system on 192.168.0.116 so when we try to communicate it works fine but cant debug it using **wireshark**.
My websocket is running on port 8001 so i tried using

```
tcp.port==8001
```

but no result found so i then tried it on http 
my ip in lan is 192.168.0.219 and port 8001. so

```
http.host == 192.168.0.219 && tcp.port == 8001
```

but no results found.
Is there anything else that i can try to debug my websocket.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally i found it.

When i put

```
tcp.dstport == 8001 || tcp.srcport == 8001
```

At that time i can capture it.

Comment: WebSockets do not necessarily use port 8001. For example, Openshift websockets currently use port 8000: https://blog.openshift.com/paas-websockets/

Answer (score 30):

You can also filter to show only WebSocket packets by using a display filter:

```
(websocket)
```

Comment: Seems to work sometimes for me, working for the socket connection on stackoverflow, but not for the website I am building for some reason, I wonder if its because the site I am building is ssl/tsl?

Answer (score 4):

Check the syntax for filters, in your case, it should be `tcp port 8001`.

Step by step:

1. Capture options
2. Select the network interface
3. Fill the filed next to the button "Capture Filter:" with `tcp port 8001`
4. Start

Comment: You have to add more information, such as what specifically you tried, in which platform have you tried, version, etc.  In my case, I use that kind of filters very often in Linux and it works.  Also, check if you are running wireshark with privileges (superuser o suid) and check if you are filtering the right network interface.

Comment: Which network interface should I select? 
ETA - I selected Loopback and it worked