# How to check WebSocket JSON payload?

Tags: java, json

I have a web application that sends messages through websocket. They are JSON payloads.
When you click on certain buttons the application sends the payload. Is there a way to intercept the payload?
What JAVA library can I use to check if the payload is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java JSON APIs like Gson etc. and try parsing the JSON string into your desired Java class. Each API have their own unique exception that are thrown if your payload is incorrect and impossible to be parsed.

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem of intercepting the payload. I would need to somehow connect to the endpoint and grab it from there. Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: You can create a Java websocket server endpoint class with "ServerEndpoint" annotation by using javax.websocket.server. You can intercept a websocket request by a method with "OnOpen" and receive messages with method having "OnMessage" annotation. Take a look at https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/websocket_client_and_server_endpoint

Comment: The problem with this is that whenever I send more than one message I only get the first one, the one that is sent onOpen. I'm not sure how to deal with multiple messages. There's no example regarding this.

Comment: You might need to flush on client side maybe?

Answer (score 0):

one of the simpler way just to check the payload for any HTTP communication is to use tools like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), just start he packet capture with http tcp filter and it would give all the interactions (with HTTP payload)[initial handshake etc]. For websocket interation, it also supports websocket filter.

Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650083/how-to-debug-websockets-with-wireshark)